# Writing to subprocess.Popen.stdin not Executing Correctly

Tags: python-3.x

Why do the "subprocess.Popen.stdin.write" commands seem to fail?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import os
import subprocess

bash = subprocess.Popen(['bash'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

(shell=True: see edit 2)

```
bash.stdin.write(b'echo foo\n')
print(bash.stdout.readline())
bash.stdin.write(b'echo bar\n')
print(bash.stdout.readline())
```

edit: It blocks at the first subprocess.Popen.stdout.readline(), probably because there are no lines in subprocess.Popen.stdout. It is supposed to print out:

```
foo
bar
```

edit 2: This still hangs.

Comment: Do you get any error message? What does it do and what it is supposed to do?

Comment: it won't do it. bash has a number of execution modes and what you are looking for is shell mode. what you can do is to do `shell=True` when you call `Popen` but you will create a security hole. you should check the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: what happens you do bash? apparently it looks working for me, it's like this because your bash print some of these when it launches in shell mode. another solution to this is `ptty`, it's more correct but more complicated. if you want to do the right thing, you will want to check that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer for my question works as long as you run GNU/Linux(maybe others, haven't tested) and install pexpect("pip install pexpect").

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
"""
Python command line software control example
"""
import pexpect

encode = 'UTF-8'

bash = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/env bash', encoding=encode)

bash.sendline('echo foo')
print(bash.readline())
bash.sendline('echo bar')
print(bash.readline())
```